# Resign Rental Contract Germany

Tags: germany, rental, contracts

I have signed a rental contract in Germany, but I don't like the location that much.

The contract start September first, 2016. According to the terms I have to give a 3 months notice period before leaving it.

I haven't even entered the apartment, since when I ask this question is August 27th.

Is there anything I can do to avoid entering it? If not, how can I notify them that I want to leave in 3 months? Is this a letter I need to sign and send over to them, or, is there anything I can do quickly.

PS.: I have found another apartment.

**UPDATE**

I have the following clauses in my contract( under Kündigungsfristen
):

2. Bei unbestimmter Mietdauer sind beide Parteien berechtigt, diesen Mietvertrag schriftlich spätestens am 03. Werktag eines Kalendermonats (entscheidend für die Wahrung der Frist ist der Eingang bei dem Vertragspartner) zum Ablauf des übernächsten Monats zu kündigen. Die Kündigungsfrist des Vermieters verlängert sich nach Ablauf von fünf bzw. acht Jahren seit Beginn des Mietverhältnisses um jeweils drei Monate.
3. Nach Ablauf des Verzichts auf die Ausübung des Kündigungsrechts läuft das Mietverhältnis auf unbestimmte Zeit, wenn es nicht rechtzeitig zuvor zum Zeitpunkt dieses Ablaufes oder zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt gekündigt worden ist.
4. Setzt der Mieter nach Beendigung des Mietverhältnisses den Gebrauch der Mieträume fort, so verlängert sich das Mietverhältnis abweichend von § 545 BGB nicht.
   __

**Update 2**

I found the following Web site giving some tips on how to finish the Contract:
https://www.mieterverband.ch/mv/mietrecht-beratung/ratgeber-mietrecht/top-themen/kuendigung-durch-mieter.html

There is a template of the letter of resignation.

**My question is: How do I ensure the Landlord Received it?**

And in My case - there is a company taking care, and making the communication.

Comment: How would those conditions apply to your lease agreement?

Comment: Hi @Dorothy, I did not get your question. My understanding so far is that I need to stay 3 months at least, due to the Notice time.

Comment: sorry, my fault; my German is only fair; as I read it, you have to give a three month notice so, if you've signed the contract and gave notice now, before move-in, you are still obligated to pay three months of rent, even if you don't live there.

Comment: The 2nd clause is about unlimited rentals, but implies a limited one is possible. If there is a fixed rental period, usually leaving early is impossible.

Answer (score 6):

It is correct that the contract binds you to pay for three months, even if you cancel it right now, before moving in.

However, typically landlords in Germany are willing to accept a *qualified* replacement for you ('Nachmieter') - they are not forced in any way, but it is quite common; from my experience, 1/2 - 3/4 of all rental 'notice periods' end short with the renter presenting one or more appropriate replacements to the landlord. Consider that after your notice period, the landlord would like to have a renter right away, and you do the work for him by finding and presenting them right now, he should be glad.

So you should try to find someone who is willing to rent the location for the same conditions as you have, and present him to the landlord as a potential replacement. Note the word *qualified* - ability to pay the rent and other criteria will be applied by the landlord, he would not go for worse than you in any way, why should he.

Note that if the landlord doesn't want to do that (for whatever reason), you are just out of luck. However, if you give him the keys or never move in, and he *does* rent it out (behind your back) within that period, you no longer own rent - the landlord cannot double-dip.